# Does Google Chrome send INCOGNITO search history data to Google?

Tags: google, chrome

Type Ctrl + Shift + N. Then type DIVIDED WE FALL and then click enter. Click a search result that takes you to YouTube. Go back to the search results. Retype "DIVIDED WE FALL by Valarie Kaur". Click enter. Click on the result that takes you to Vimeo. You see the full documentary there and watch it.

If all this were done on a normal window, it would be saved in your history tab (ctrl+h), regardless of you have a google account or not. Most likely, this search history will also be sent to Google, regardless of you delete it manually or not.

Will this happen if I use an incognito mode? That is, will Google see my "search journey" (i.e. what I searched for, what I clicked, what I retyped, what website I visited, what video I watched there...) if done in Incognito window? Does Chrome send search history to Google if the search is done in Incognito? If it isn't incognito, then surely the search history is sent to Google regardless of anything, but is that so for Incognito mode as well?

Comment: You asked the same before: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/240570/does-google-collect-and-store-data-about-activity-done-in-incognito-mode

Comment: @user245472 Nope, that is fundamentally a different question. Please see *User marianoju*'s answer's comments. Thanks

Comment: @SteffenUlrich's answer on your previous post answers bot for Google and for Google Chrome, so this is a duplicate

Comment: ***You*** send the search by using the search engine. It's not clear what you are asking or how this is different from your other question.

Comment: @schroeder If I search or visit a website or a specific page within it on a normal window, it gets stored in my history tab AS WELL AS sent to Google's data centers. But if I do the same thing in Incognito(visiting a specific page on a specific website), obviously my PC won't show it in the history tab, but does Google know it? If Google gets to see everyone's history tab, does it get to see everyone's **hypothetical** "Incognito" history tab?

Comment: Of course google knows it because you visited the site and made the search. It doesn't have to come from some log in your browser because they just log the live activity on the server ...

Comment: @schroeder +1 *"... because they just log the live activity on the server"* -- So do they log the live activity if the live activity was done in incognito? If yes, I will close/leave this question. Thank you

Comment: We've already talked about this in your other questions. Incognito does not make you anonymous to the servers. Please look up, again,what incognito mode means or just read the default page that pops up in Chrome when you open an incognito window ...

Comment: Thank you schroeder for confirming. As I said before, I am not tech-savvy so I generally ask for a yes/no answer, although I do try to understand the reasons behind things. Like you don't want/need to learn how you or your loved one developed a fibroma, you just want to know how to remove them. Thank you for coordinating.